# Approve/Reject MS Flow from Power Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powerapp, ms-flow

I want to add the MS Flow Approval Page inside a SharePoint modern page (i wrote another question regarding this @ [Embed MS Flow Approvals page inside a modern sharepoint page using iframe](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/286993/embed-ms-flow-approvals-page-inside-a-modern-sharepoint-page-using-iframe) ), and seems that simply embedding the MS Flow Page inside SharePoint modern page is not supported.. so i am think of building a PowerApp which show the user's MS Flow Approval items >> then embed the PowerApp inside SharePoint modern page. Till now i did the following:-

First of all this is the MS Flow approval page i am talking about which i am unable to embed inside SharePoint:-

[image]

Now i created a new Power App >> i specify the Approvals as the data source >> where i got the MS Flow approvals requests as follow:-

[image]

but i am not sure how i can add the ability to Approve,Reject the requests + how to show the corresponding file (as in the MS flow Approval Page)? .. Now if this is too complicated (to rebuild the MS Flow Approval Page inside powerapp), then how i can add a link inside PowerApp's items which will redirect the user to related MS Flow item inside the MS flow approval page? so for example if i click on one of the above items inside powerapp, it should take me to the related item inside MS Flow Approvals page where i can Approve/Reject the request and view the related document which caused the Flow to run,, is this possible as a simpler approach?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do it without CDS. The state of Flow and approval are managed in CDS and data spreads across multiple entities. This is not easy to understand but if you give enough time you may understand it. Having said that I came across entities that cannot be edited by user (I am still working on this part) These entities manage all complex and simple tasks related to approval e.g. awaiting holding requests, responses reassignment. You will have to explore how this stuff works to make your powerapp work.

[image]

**Update**

If i check the network trace after clicking approval in Action tab i see a GUID which is the same present in entity. I have tried getting around this but couldn't give enough time, so i don't have anything conclusive for you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply.. so it is even complex to just build  a list of link which takes the user to the MS flow approvals? also can you please explain what your image provides?

Comment: to build that link you need a ID for your approval request which is again stored within an entity in form of GUID with that i belive you can create the URL

Comment: can you provide more info?

Comment: I see there are restriction on entity and it won't be easy to get this working.

Comment: referring back to your point `You won't be able to do it without CDS`.. now i have CDS connectors so can i benefit from them?